# Load and run .m file with CDF Player Pro

Tags: cdfplayer

I have a program written with Mathematica, splitted in several .m files which are loaded at runtime using the `Get` command. Using Mathematica it runs fine but when I try to run `Get["something.m"]` with CDF Player Pro from a .cdf-file it just returns `$Failed`.

Is it even possible to load and run seperate .m or .nb files using the CDF Player (Pro) via the `Get` command?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @RolfMertig Then do you have a clue why running `Get` fails using CDF Player but works using Mathematica? Do you have any source that says that it should work?

Comment: `$Path` may be different. You can also work with `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory@EvaluationNotebook[]]` before using `Get`. You could also post a minimal working example here. Or send this to Wolfram support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally contacted the Support. Apparently the CDF Player can only load files using the `Get` command which are inside its installation directory. I copied my program into

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram CDF Player\11.3\AddOns\Applications\MyApp
```

which works fine now. I wish there was some documentation with information like this...

Comment: So Free Player or Player Pro? For the latter it is not true, it can Import/Export whatever you want. Just make sure you the file is on path or add full path.

Comment: @Kuba Player Pro. Yes, `Import` and `Export` do work but `Get` does not when the file you want to load is not inside the installation directory. These are completely different methods anyway. I edited my answer to clarify it's about the Get command and not about Import/Export.